# Windows (desktop) странное поведение поля ввода

Tags: flutter, dart

Windows (desktop) странное поведение поля ввода. В поле ввода я ввожу текст Hello World. Первое слово Hello вводится нормально, но после того, как я ввожу пробел и начинаю вводить слово World, это слово начинает вводиться большими буквами WORLD. В мобильном и браузерном варианте, все работает нормально. Может уже кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Возможно, это какой-то баг? У меня последняя версия студии, последняя SDK Flutter. Может это только у меня такое, попробуйте сделать у себя. Далее полный код и скриншот. 
***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str = '';

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1(String value) {
  setState(() {
   _str = value;
  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextField(
       cursorColor: Colors.pink,
       onChanged: (String value) { _f1(value); },
      ),
     ),
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment.center,
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.pink,
       fontSize: 36.0,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если делать через TextEditingController, проблема остаётся?

Comment: Да, проблема остается.

Comment: Проверил на https://dartpad.dev/ на MacOS, проблем нет.

Comment: Уважаемый nazarpunk! Вы проверьте у себя на компьютере. Создайте приложение Windows, если такое возможно на MacOS. Вы поймите, код один и тод же, а работает на телефоне и в веб нормально, а в оконном приложении так, как показано на скриншоте.